Dynamic url calling using slug failed in Laravel
I am working on a business listing website and using following routes working fine

Route::get('/', [HomeController::class, 'index'])->name('home');
Route::get('/country/{country}', [CountryController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/cuisine/{cuisineSlug}', [CuisineController::class, 'cuisine']);
Route::get('/food/{food}', [FoodController::class, 'index']);

these redirects to home page or show 404 error

Route::get('/{country}/{state}', [StateController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/{city}/{restaurant}', [RestaurantController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/{city}/{restaurantCategory}', [CityRestaurantCategoryController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('/{city}/{foodCategory}', [CityFoodCategoryController::class, 'index']);

is there a way I can bind them, so that Laravel don't get confused that which parameter it belongs to.

you can't have routes like that, there is no way for the router to differentiation the difference between them as the number of parameters is exactly the same (the first matching route is the one that is used based on the pattern) ... how would it know that something is a "city" or a "country" or a "restaurant" or a "foodCategory"? .... city/{city}/restaurant/{restaurant} perhaps something like that

I recommend that you watch this old but good video. those routes are only possible with more on URI, check docs how the do it.
